# How can I access all variables from the main program in a class imported by it?

Tags: python, pygame

I know that this question has been answered multiple times but the answers don't quite solve my problem.

In my case, I need to use the screen (and multiple other variables like `level`) from the main program in a class that is imported by it.

A common answer is to use the variables as a parameter. This doesn't work for me as I don't want to pass 5+ parameters every time I make a class.

Another answer is to use `from main import *`. This doesn't work as well because some of the variables are created after importing the class.

Is there a solution to this?

Edit: This is how my program is structured:

`main.py`:

```
import module

screenX = 1000
screenY = 500
...

player = module.Player()
```

`module.py`:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = screenX
        self.y = screenY
        ...

    def go(self):
        self.x += 1
        if self.touchs(level):
            self.die()

    def touchs(self, object):
        ...

    def die(self):
        ...
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: The variables would change over time but the parameters would stay the same. I also have to change the parameters inside the classes so that doesn't work either. I edited the post with a rough structure of my program.

Comment: Why you have to have the parameters in your main program? Can't you just put them into a common module?

Comment: The solution is to pass the 5+ parameters. Have you considered aggregating them, so that e.g. you have *one* object ``screen`` with ``screen.x = 1000`` and ``screen.y = 500``? How many distinct parameters do you actually have?

Comment: @finefoot Exactly. I have a level editor and `Player` has to know the changed level.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks, I can pass screenX and screenY as parameters. However the variable `level` changes over time but parameters don't.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen That's not a bad idea! I will try it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A common answer is to use the variables as a parameter. This doesn't work for me as I don't want to pass 5+ parameters every time I make a class.

I think you're underestimating how flexible that approach can be. Have a look at the following example:

`main.py`

```py
import module

settings = {
    "foo": "bar",
    # ...
}

player = module.Player(settings)
player.print_foo()
settings["foo"] = "baz"
player.print_foo()
```

`module.py`

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings
    def print_foo(self):
        print(self.settings["foo"])
```

Comment: If that works it's a wonderful solution! However I will probably use @MrBean Bremen's approach as it's easier and I can change the variables in module.py.